Jax: Passing a constant argument into a scanned function
I'm refactoring a project written in Jax.
There's a function, let's call it foo, that gets fed into jax.lax.scan. It has an argument bar that is currently part of the carry (i.e. the first argument, which is a tuple of different variables that gets passed ahead to the next call.) I noticed that the bar argument doesn't change throughout a single scan, i.e. the function unpacks it from the received carry and packs it into the returned carry without modification. I figured I better remove it from the carry, but I couldn't figure out how to do that.
At first I tried removing it from the carry, adding it as a keyword argument to the function and changing the scan call to use partial(foo, bar=bar). However, I noticed it was slow. The foo function is jitted and I'm guessing that the way I added the argument makes it be jitted every single time instead of just once.
I then tried to feed bar into the xs argument, but I got builtins.ValueError: scan got value with no leading axis to scan over: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.
Is there a recommended way to do this?

This question will be difficult to answer without a minimal reproducible example; please edit your question to add one.
